# Responsive Web Design - Resolution Independent

Tags: layout, responsive-design, resolution-independence

I've been investigating different alternatives for creating responsive web sites/apps and I can't find one that is **Resolution Independent** for mobile devices.

I'm looking for a layout that looks the same in every mobile device with any given resolution. For example: the [Google Plus Site](http://plus.google.com) for mobile browsers. I've open the site with chrome mobile in my **LG G3 (1440 x 2560)** and in an **iPhone 5S (640 x 1136)** and the site looks **exactly the same**, and the desktop site it's almost no responsive at all.

I've been using the bootstrap 3 grid system, but bootstrap uses the resolution of the view-port.

My question is: How can I achieve this type of Layout?

Comment: Are those screen resolutions or the browser resolution?

Comment: Also clarify what you mean by looks the same, the layout is different on mobile than desktop

Comment: @Huangism screen resolutions

Comment: @Huangism what I mean is the the mobile layout looks the same and in the same proportion in all resolutions I've tested (IN MOBILES), YES the desktop looks different and it's hardly responsive to different viewport widths as you resize the desktop browser

Comment: Their desktop version does not transform into the mobile one when you resize the browser all the way down. If you set your element's width in % then it gives you the feeling of everything is not changing much

Comment: @Huangism are you saying I should user % in the mobile version to achieve responsiveness as the google plus mobile site?

Comment: It's a start, there is a lot of work in doing responsive website and it's hard to explain everything. You are better off googling and doing research